# GET ​/safes​/{safe-add}​/ returns user as owner but GET ​/owners​/{user-add}​/safes​/ does not return safe-add

Tags: gnosis-safe

When I create a new safe. The query - https://cocosafe.efprivacyscaling.org/txs/api/v1/safes/0x145dBB623888759724B5CD8dB040A9B9c630e37a/ returns expected owner address (i.e. **0xF452A460492Edc52FE3590a43a355529507b05e6**).

But when I query https://cocosafe.efprivacyscaling.org/txs/api/v1/owners/0xF452A460492Edc52FE3590a43a355529507b05e6/safes/ , returned safe array is empty.

I can confirm that this issue is only with /txs api, since safe-react UI (using https://cocosafe.efprivacyscaling.org/cgw) displays the newly created safe.

Since, I am running my own instance of safe-infrastructure, I suspect that there's some config that I have forgotten. It can't be web hook, since I am querying /txs directly. Any idea what's wrong?

---

**Edit 1:**

The query returns response as expected now. I think this is happening due to some caching issue. If that's the case, what configuration is required to clear up the cache as expected?

Answer (score 0):

As this endpoint is heavy on the database it is cached for 1 hour. You would have to adjust the source code of the tx service to change this as this is currently not configurable.

To adjust this in code you can change the [method_decorator of the OwnersView get function](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-transaction-service/blob/master/safe_transaction_service/history/views.py#L1017).

Feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-transaction-service/issues/new?assignees=Uxio0&labels=enhancement&template=feature_request.md&title=) to make this configurable.